# UISegmentedControl and UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, gesture, uisegmentedcontrol, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a view with `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and `UISegmentedControl`.

Segmented control has different styles for highlighted and selected state.

The problem is when I start pan gesture inside `UISegmentedControl` then it sometimes stays highlighted, but should be with selected style.

I tried to disable it when the touch is inside some area, but sometimes it still works.

How to solve this issue? It is clearly seen when segmented control has for example different font colors for highlighted and selected states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use this method to prevent touch on specific controls:(for example:)

```
- (BOOL) gestureRecognizer: (UIGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer
       shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if (touch.view == sliderButton)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

You can replace 'sliderButton' with your segment control or whichever view you want.

Comment: something is wrong in your code or in my one because touch.view can mean something, but not the UISegmentedControl. But however that may be thanks for your help.

Comment: did you use segmentcontrol.view in the place of 'sliderButton' ?